# Using date for the 'dl' element key?

Tags: html, html-lists, semantic-markup

I am creating an article list. An article list consists of date and article title:

> 2019-04-14 article_name1
>   2019-04-15 article_name2
>   2019-04-16 article_name3

I can use some list elements at this time. `ol`, `dl`, `ul` etc. When deciding which of these is appropriate, I wondered if it would be appropriate to set the date as the key for the `dl` element and the article name etc.

```html
<dl>
  <dt>2019-04-14</dt>
  <dd>article_name1</dd>
  <dt>2019-04-15</dt>
  <dd>article_name2</dd>
  <dt>2019-04-16</dt>
  <dd>article_name3</dd>
</dl>
```

According to HTML standard, it was found that the usage of [`dl` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) is limited because the markup of the conversation is inappropriate:

> The `dl` element is inappropriate for marking up dialogue. See some examples of how to mark up dialogue.

However, I did not know whether it was appropriate or inappropriate in the article list.

**Is it inappropriate to use a date as the key of the `dl` element and write an article name etc. as its description?**

Also, is it inappropriate to write the article name and date as a key in the key?

```html
<dl>
  <dt>article_name1</dt>
  <dd>2019-04-14</dd>
  <dt>article_name2</dt>
  <dd>2019-04-15</dd>
  <dt>article_name3</dt>
  <dd>2019-04-16</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Since the spec doesn't say one way or the other, this is arguably a matter of opinion. But the problem with dialogue as a list of name-value pairs is that the names repeat each time the character says something, which is not what one would expect of an association list. So, as long as each date appears only once in the list, I'd say it was appropriate.